# Populate elements of a list with elements from another list

Tags: python, list

I want to fill the empty spaces in result with the elements in order.

```
resultelse=["hello", "you", "are"]
result=["","",""]
for a in resultelse:
   result[result.index("")] = a
   print(result)

['hello', '', '']
['hello', 'you', '']
['hello', 'you', 'are']
```

but i only want the last set

Comment: Move the print to after the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You track the progress of algorithm during it's execution. The only thing you need is just to let it finish. Just move the print outside the loop:

```
resultelse=["hello", "you", "are"]
result=["","",""]
for a in resultelse:
   result[result.index("")] = a
print(result)
```